# Help me find my BMX brand please!

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]
[image]
Hey!! So a few years ago, an old man gave me this bmx but it was very old so me and my dad decided to fix it. The seat is new and so are the tires. The rest is all original, could someone help me?
I have never seen this type of frame tho, it has an "X" on it, as you can see

Comment: Nice looking bike - but there's nothing there which looks distinctive.  Simply enjoy riding it, maintain it periodically, and it should last decades.

Answer (score 0):

this site might help you to find this old BMX bike
https://bmxmuseum.coI used it to find my 80's BMX lately